# Importing DWG / DXF into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, autocad

I'm having some trouble converting a simple site schematic drawn in AutoCad into a shapefile for use in QGIS. A co-worker who works remotely has done the Autocad Drawings, and has exported as shapefiles, and sent me the .dwg, .dxf files, and when I load into qgis, they don't resemble the actual map drawn. It looks to me like maybe the autocad file might have been set up incorrectly? I've never worked with Autocad, wondering if someone may be able to shed some light on whats going wrong. I'll attach a pdf of the schematic he has done, and a screenshot of what appears in QGIS when I load his shp export, or dxf. i'll also attach the .dxf and .dwg file if someone wanted to have a look at them and see if there was something obviously wrong.

[image: This is a screenshot of the pdf export my coworker made in Autocad]

List item

[image: This is what appears when I load the .shp or .dxf into QGIS]

Comment: Is you coworker inserting the data as a *reference*? AutoCAD can use references like layers in QGIS, I've not worked with this software either I have encountered this problem creating maps from DWGs.. the *actual data* was in another file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5NMA3jQuGYW2P5oqjmtveuTvVcYpLM_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YzxaGNtl8Mr6klH8V0wGdKRjMC-t8F1W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael, I will have him check

Answer (score 1):

The DXF consists of 2 parts.

1) The card frame / legend

2) The actual geodata

Your screenshot shows only the map frame (you can see at the coordinates)
The data itself is in the north[image]

The data itself is in 3 areas[image]

Comment: Thanks! that makes much more sense. I appreciate the help. I will explain to him and try have him "clean up" his autocad project.

Answer (score 0):

The shapes are actually here, and possibly at the right coordinates. Although, you have to import them in the right coordinate system. If you know which CRS your co-worker used, just enter that into QGIS. By looking at a previous post of yours, and some educated guess, it seems like the coordinate system is NAD83 UTM14N (ESPG: 26914), which looks about right :

[image]

Then, look at the linestrings, which is where your data seems to be. What you showed in your screenshots is at the (0, 0) coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that you need to know what coordinates your coworkers CAD file is in, I think more importantly it must be Coordinated CAD data to begin with or it will not show up correctly. Once you find out if both of those are true, then you should assign it the projection you would like and it should just drop in right where it is supposed to.